MongoDB partitioning by chunks with one shard is reasonable? Partitioning at one server
I would like to get the result in mongodb similar to partitioning in postgresql. That is, I want that on one instance of the database, without a cluster, without additional nodes, the data is distributed, for example, by date, and when I request data in the collection, then mongodb would scan in parallel only those sub-collections that meet the condition.
For example, a collection of type
{
 date: ISODate('2024-03-03T05:05:05')
 temperature: 25
}

And When I will make a request of type
db.my_collection.find({date: { $gt: ISODate('2024-03-03') } })

Then only sub-collections that store data newer than 2024-03-03 would be scanned in parallel.
This is how partitioning works in PostgreSQL.
I repeat that I am not interested in the topic of sharding and load distribution on different servers, I have only one server with a very large amount of data.

{date: { $gt: ISODate('2024-03-03') } } vs "only sub-collections that store data older than 2024-03-03 would be scanned" - No, with $gt it would be newer than 2024-03-03.

This sounds a little bit like time series

MongoDB doesn't have Partitioning like that. That could be done with Sharding but since you don't want to do that, your only option is to create collections and move data periodically.
But the collections must have different names and you can't do db.my_collection.find() to automatically select the right collection. That's what sharding would do. You'll need a get_collection_for_date('2024-03-03').find(...).
And then you'll need to handle date ranges for queries which apply across multiple collections and combine results from multiple queries to different collections. Maybe even construct the multiple queries using unionWith. None of this can be done transparently.
If your concern is about the number of documents, time to retrive documents:

Use Indexing for fields frequently used in Find/Match queries, like your date.

‼ Instead of having one document per reading/temperature, each document should have the readings for a specific time-range. See Group Data with the Bucket Pattern.

So instead of having documents like

{
  date: ISODate('2024-03-03T05:05:05'),
  temperature: 25
}


The docs should have a range of readings:

{
  from_date: ISODate("2024-03-03T05:00:00Z"),
  to_date: ISODate("2024-03-03T06:00:00Z"),
  readings: [
    { date: ISODate("2024-03-03T05:05:05Z"), temperature: 25 },
    { date: ISODate("2024-03-03T05:05:06Z"), temperature: 27 },
    ...
  ]
}


Use an actual Time Series Collection.



When I use only an index by date, when the size of the collection grows to 100,000,000 documents, the performance of insert queries drops very much, and I have an idea to divide one collection into smaller ones under some specific condition, so that my collections contain only part of the data and work efficiently with insert and find queries on this data.

The speed of insertion into the collection when it contains 100,000 documents - 20,000 insertions per second
The speed of insertion into the collection when it contains 100,000,000 documents - 1,000 insertions per second
And I'm afraid that when the number of documents reaches 1,000,000,000, productivity will drop to near zero.

@RomanTiukh Are you using insertOne or insertMany? Is "20,000 insertions per second" just loading data into MongoDB or do you actually get 20,000 readings every second? With the Bucket pattern, you could store at least 1,000 readings in one document; bucket by minute or by second as required. Then fewer insertions are needed. Also, definitely use Time Series Collection instead of regular collections. I should add, creating many collections based only on time ranges is an Anti-pattern. And requires a lot of code/effort to then query across collections based on the required time range.

Please checkout MongoDB Indexes.
Indexes are special data structures that store a small portion of the collection's data set in an easy-to-traverse form. MongoDB indexes use a B-tree data structure.
Full Documentation: MongoDB Indexes
In your case you need to add index on date field in your collection to limit the documents for scanning.

Thanks for helping, I answered about indexes at comment to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78528438/11607952
